# Amazon Elastick BeanStalk error: Failed to create the AWS Elastic Beanstalk application version

Tags: amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have today a strange issue for Amazon Elastick BeanStalk: for my instances I cannot upload application:

> XXX@-Vostro-2520:~/git_projects/ProjectBlog (test-env)$ git aws.push --environment Project-Blog-test
> Updating the AWS Elastic Beanstalk environment Project-Blog-test...
> **Error: Failed to create the AWS Elastic Beanstalk application version**

I did test it for 2 instances: PHP and RoR apps.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I solved  this on my own:)

Amazon EB allows only for 500 Application Versions. So  I logged in to console -> Elastick BeanStalk -> Action -> View Application Versions

On these page I selected and deleted some of olded files uploaded to Amazon EB. After it I was able to upload new versions with EB scripts.

Comment: This was exactly the problem I encountered. It would be nice if the error indicated this was the cause.

Comment: very helpful, had to scour around for possible solutions until I found this **thumbs up**

Answer (score 0):

Heads up that the error may also appear if you have invalid characters in the commit description. Not sure what these are to AWS, but I got the same error with the characters "http://".